# How do I override default codec in circe?

Tags: json, scala, circe

I'd like to encode `Array[Byte]` fields of my case classes as Base64 strings. For some reason Circe doesn't pick up my codec using default one instead that converts byte array into json array of ints.

What should I do to fix it ? Here is my minimized code

```
import io.circe.generic.JsonCodec

sealed trait DocumentAttribute

@JsonCodec
sealed case class DAAudio(title: Option[String], performer: Option[String], waveform: Option[Array[Byte]], duration: Int) extends DocumentAttribute

@JsonCodec
sealed case class DAFilename(fileName: String) extends DocumentAttribute

object CirceEncodersDecoders {
  import io.circe._
  import io.circe.generic.extras._
  import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._

  implicit val arrayByteEncoder: Encoder[Array[Byte]] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Array[Byte]] { bytes ⇒
    Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(bytes)
  }

  val printer: Printer = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true, reuseWriters = true)
  implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("kind").withSnakeCaseConstructorNames.withSnakeCaseMemberNames

  implicit val DocumentAttributeEncoder: Encoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val DocumentAttributeDecoder: Decoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveDecoder
}

object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import CirceEncodersDecoders._

    import io.circe.parser._
    import io.circe.syntax._

    val attributes: List[DocumentAttribute] = List(
      DAAudio(Some("title"), Some("perform"), Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(_.toByte).toArray), 15),
      DAFilename("filename")
    )
    val j2 = attributes.asJson
    val decoded2 = decode[List[DocumentAttribute]](j2.noSpaces)
    println(decoded2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
implicit val DocumentAttributeEncoder: Encoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveEncoder
```

`circe` tries to get suitable `Encoder` for `DAFilename` and `DAAudio`. However, since those already exist (by means of `@JsonCodec` on individual classes), it does not re-derive them from scratch using generics and your `Encoder[Array[Byte]]` at scope - which you want.

So you can either get rid of `@JsonCodec` (so it auto-derives codecs for `DAFilename` and `DAAudio` together with `DocumentAttribute`) or trigger re-derivation manually:

```
implicit val AudioDecoder: Encoder[DAAudio] = deriveEncoder // takes priority over existing one
implicit val DocumentAttributeEncoder: Encoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveEncoder // AudioDecoder will be used here
```

You also need to build a `Decoder` for `Array[Byte]` and repeat the process above for `Decoder`s, otherwise it will try to parse Base64 string as a list of ints, resulting in a failure.

Comment: You have commented decoding code from the question, so your answer is not full.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk I believe I have provided enough information for OP to be able to figure it out, and I did mention that he is missing the Decoder.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that `@JsonCodec` annotations don't work with a custom encoder for `Array[Byte]`.

Here is all the stuff that need for encoding and decoding of your classes with `circe`:

```
object CirceEncodersDecoders2 {
  val printer: Printer = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true, reuseWriters = true)
  implicit val arrayByteEncoder: Encoder[Array[Byte]] =
    Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Array[Byte]](Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString)
  implicit val arrayByteDecoder: Decoder[Array[Byte]] =
    Decoder.decodeString.map[Array[Byte]](Base64.getDecoder.decode)
  implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("kind").withSnakeCaseConstructorNames.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
  implicit val audioEncoder: Encoder[DAAudio] = deriveEncoder[DAAudio]
  implicit val audioDecoder: Decoder[DAAudio] = deriveDecoder[DAAudio]
  implicit val filenameEncoder: Encoder[DAFilename] = deriveEncoder[DAFilename]
  implicit val filenameDecoder: Decoder[DAFilename] = deriveDecoder[DAFilename]
  implicit val documentAttributeEncoder: Encoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveEncoder[DocumentAttribute]
  implicit val documentAttributeDecoder: Decoder[DocumentAttribute] = deriveDecoder[DocumentAttribute]
}
```

If you are not limited in selection of JSON parser/serializer, then you can try a more efficient solution using [`jsoniter-scala`](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala).

*DISCLAIMER*: I'm an author of this library.

Here are results of benchmarks for both implementations:

```
[info] Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt        Score           Error   Units
[info] ListOfAdtWithBase64Benchmark.readCirce           thrpt 5   114927.343 ±   7910.068 ops/s
[info] ListOfAdtWithBase64Benchmark.readJsoniterScala   thrpt 5  1818299.170 ± 162757.404 ops/s
[info] ListOfAdtWithBase64Benchmark.writeCirce          thrpt 5   117982.635 ±   8942.816 ops/s
[info] ListOfAdtWithBase64Benchmark.writeJsoniterScala  thrpt 5  4281752.461 ± 319953.287 ops/s
```

Full sources are [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/commit/f36364015ade18c03f2b4ce0ba0783a28a03a65c).

Comment: `@JsonCodec` annotations indeed do work with custom decoders, as long as those are available in scope at the moment of derivation, as do `deriveEncoder` and `deriveDecoder`. Your code is redundant since you don't need to manually derive instances for all the subtypes of the sealed trait nor do you need to pass type parameter to `deriveXXX` explicitly.

Comment: That, and you advertise your own library without explicit disclaimer, assuming OP is looking for speed (while there are also other reasons to be using circe, like optics, yaml support, http4s and/or fs2 integration), which is mentioned nowhere, with a benchmark results that take half of the answer instead of a code of how the problem would actually be solved.